# Java CPU resource hog, 100%

Tags: java, cpu-usage

I have written a program which when it starts up runs about 96% CPU and then very quickly tips the CPU to 100% before crashing. I need to trace what is constantly being done by the CPU whether it is the program running though or a particular method or call being worked on.

Any suggestions or links?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you lease post your code (particularly where the crash occurs), along with a stack trace to help us debug it? If you don't, we can't really help you. Thanks!

Comment: which version of java are you using ?

Comment: Using JDK 1.6, the code is too extensive for a post here though I could host it elsewhere for now I want to avoid doing so. If from these answers I can see what is abusing/staying/using the CPU then I can modify the code appropriately. By crash I mean the programs keeps running, prints keep coming but the GUI becomes unresponsive, unsure what exactly it is doing.

Comment: As per your description it seems you are doing some long processing in your UI thread or it might be going in some infinite loop or some dead-lock scenario. If you have a single threaded code the easiest step would be to use `System.out.println` for logging purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Java VisualVM](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/index.html) should help. It is a tool that is included in the standard JDK. It allows you to profile and inspect a running Java program. It should be in the same directory as your javac executable.

Here is a [quick synopsis](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) of the command line to use to invoke the tool.

Comment: He has not mentioned the JDK version and the jvisualvm comes only with JDK 1.6 and up. Although its a great utility to use. +1 .

Comment: @Favonius: Good call! There are still plenty of old versions of Java in the wild. I can't assume that everyone will be using the latest.

Comment: I am using JDK 1.6 so will try this out. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you can start with profiling your application.

As you have not mentioned the Java version therefore i am safely assuming SUN JDK 1.5.

For a starter you can use:

1. http://jrat.sourceforge.net/ OR
2. NetBeans IDE profiler for checking the bottle necks in your program.

Secondly, you can use JConsole for monitoring the memory usage in your application. Its in your `<JDK HOME>\bin`.

If you are using SUN JDK 1.6 then as A. Levy mentioned, use jvisualvm for CPU and Heap profiling.

And possible then post your code snippet.

Comment: +1 for alternate profilers. I'll try to remember JRAT if I ever need to profile on a pre 1.6 JVM.